# My Email Design Isn't Responding to Mobile Devices

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-email

```html
    
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><style type="text/css">
  ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%;} 
  .ExternalClass {width: 100%;} 
  .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
  body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0 !important;}
  p { margin: 1em 0;} 
  table td { border-collapse: collapse;} 
  img {outline:0;}
  a img {border:none;}
  p {margin: 1em 0;} 
  @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width;}
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 300PX) {
   body[yahoo] .container { width:100% !important; }
   body[yahoo] .footer { width:auto !important; margin-left:0; }
   body[yahoo] .content-padding{ padding:4px !important; }
   body[yahoo] .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
   body[yahoo] .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
   body[yahoo] img { max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
   body[yahoo] .header img{max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
   body[yahoo] .photo img { width:100% !important; max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
   body[yahoo] .drop { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; float:left; clear:both;}
   body[yahoo] .footerlogo { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; padding-top:15px; float:left; clear:both;}
   body[yahoo] .nav4, body[yahoo] .nav5, body[yahoo] .nav6 { display: none !important; }
   body[yahoo] .tableBlock {width:100% !important;}
   body[yahoo] .responsive-td {width:100% !important; float:left !important; padding:0 !important; }
      .fluid, .fluid-centered {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
      }
      .fluid-centered {
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
      }
    /* MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
      body { padding: 0px !important; font-size: 16px !important; line-height: 150% !important;}
      h1 { font-size: 22px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
      h2 { font-size: 20px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
      h3 { font-size: 18px !important; line-height: normal !important;}
      .buttonstyles {
      font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif !important; 
      font-size: 16px !important; 
      color: #FFFFFF !important; 
      padding: 10px !important;
      }
    /* END OF MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   body[yahoo] .container { width:100% !important; }
   body[yahoo] .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
   body[yahoo] .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
   body[yahoo] .photo img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
   body[yahoo] .nav5, body[yahoo] .nav6 { display: none !important;}
      .fluid, .fluid-centered {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
      }
      .fluid-centered {
        margin-left: auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
      }
  }   
 </style><!--[if mso]>       <style type="text/css">           /* Begin Outlook Font Fix */           body, table, td {               font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;               font-size:16px;               color:#808080;               line-height:1;           }           /* End Outlook Font Fix */       </style>     <![endif]--></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" yahoo="fix"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td align="center" valign="top"><div style="margin:18px 0;">

<!-- END Table use to set width of email --></div>
<!--End Navi Bar-->
</td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 50%; padding-right: 5px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>
<img data-assetid="31498" src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/0dbebd2d-e383-4fb3-b7d2-775d5e3b437c.jpg" height="337" width="256" style="height:337px;width:256px;display: block;padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>
<td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 50%; padding-left: 5px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><style>
 /* Gridblock with Title Sections Pattern CSS */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        table[class="pattern"] table { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .spacer { display: none; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title,
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 2%;
            padding: 60px 20px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
 }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        table[class="pattern"] .grid-block { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 8px 0;
        }
    }
</style><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_eggo.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td>
<td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_motts.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias="">
<img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_honey_nut_cheerios.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><style>
 /* Gridblock with Title Sections Pattern CSS */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        table[class="pattern"] table { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .spacer { display: none; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title,
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 2%;
            padding: 60px 20px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
 }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        table[class="pattern"] .grid-block { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 8px 0;
        }
    }
</style><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_progresso.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="128" height="168" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td>
<td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_metamucil.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias="">
<img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/128x168_green_giant_beans.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="168" border="0" class=""></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><style>
 /* Gridblock with Title Sections Pattern CSS */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        table[class="pattern"] table { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .spacer { display: none; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title,
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 2%;
            padding: 60px 20px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
 }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        table[class="pattern"] .grid-block { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 8px 0;
        }
    }
</style><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/Holderolay.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="120" height="120" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td>
<td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/Mission.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="120" height="120" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/ReddyWhip.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120" border="0" class=""></a></td>
<td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias=""><img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/images.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120" border="0" class=""></a></td><td class="section" width="128" height="128" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #FFF;"></td><td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" alias="">
<img src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/Kraft.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120" border="0" class=""></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner" style="padding: 10px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr><td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 50%; padding-right: 3px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><style>
 /* Gridblock with Title Sections Pattern CSS */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        table[class="pattern"] table { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .spacer { display: none; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title,
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-title {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row { width: 100%; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 2%;
            padding: 60px 20px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section:first-child { margin-left: 0; }
 }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        table[class="pattern"] .grid-block { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
        table[class="pattern"] .section-row .section {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 8px 0;
        }
    }
</style><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pattern" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="grid-block" width="600" style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section-row" width="450"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="144" height="144" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #808080;">
                                    2
                                </td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="144" height="144" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #808080;">
                                    3
                                </td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td class="grid-block" width="600" style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section-row" width="450"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="144" height="144" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #808080;">
                                    2
                                </td><td class="spacer" width="8" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td><td class="section" width="144" height="144" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; background: #808080;">
                                    3
                                </td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td class="grid-block" width="600" style="padding-bottom: 8px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="responsive-td" valign="top" style="width: 50%; padding-left: 3px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" style=""><tbody><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><img data-assetid="31510" src="http://image.email-nyaaa.com/lib/fe661570736c04747414/m/3/89c228aa-d401-4f79-ba4b-1f76b230b360.jpg" height="395" width="300" style="height:395px;width:300px;display: block;padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px;"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody>
</table></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td valign="top"><center><table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5"><tr><td> </body></html>
```

I just designed an email for a upcoming campaign however i'm having a tough time with it responding correctly to mobile devices. When I check it in Litmus it does not acknowledge any breakpoints pleaseeee help. I've attached the code below:

Comment: there's no code :(

Comment: There are services online that can evaluate email designs for you. One is called Litmus, and it costs $79/month. If your job requires good-looking email designs, you may want to consider buying it.

Comment: @amphetamachine I have litmus, This will only let me know about bad links browser check etc. Im having issues with the code responding to moble.

Comment: @JosanIracheta Sorry it's been a while since i've added anything to stack exchange just uploaded the code.

Comment: Firstly, the 300px breakpoint is much smaller than just about any mobile device out there. The smallest iPhone is 320px. We mostly use 480px as the standard max-width for mobile. Also, the Gmail app doesn't support selectors. You can safely remove the body[yahoo] portions of your CSS since the Yahoo bug that corrected no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Three things stick out to me:

---

**No. 1:** You don't need brackets to define classes like this `table[class="pattern"]` anymore. `table.pattern` works in all email clients.

---

**No. 2:** 
Why is almost everything prefixed with `body[yahoo]`? This targets Yahoo! Mail and won't be rendered anywhere else. If you have your media query code prefixed like this, it won't render in iOS Mail or Gmail App.

---

**No. 3:** 
There are quite a few `<style>` tag blocks in the `<body>`. These won't be rendered by every email client, best to move them into the `<head>`.